# Docker compose don't prepend project name to volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to have docker-compose use the exact volume names I define in my yaml, instead of prepending the `projectname_`?

Ex:

```
volumes:
    postgres-data:
```

Have this volume show up as `postgres-data` instead of `projectname_postgres-data`.

Comment: Please, upvote me if was helpful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use **named volumes**:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
    your-service:
        image: ...
        ...
        volumes:
          - postgres-data:/anyfolder
        ...

volumes:
    postgres-data:
        name: <your volume name>
        external: false
```

This name will appear when you check with:

```
docker volume ls
```

Content is stored in: `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<your volume name>/_data`, so, you can use it as volume type `volume` and also type `bind`.

Docker volume can also be created in cli instead compose file using:

```
docker volume create --name <your volume name>
```

Comment: name is valid if you use Docker compose file version 3.6 for example, and docker-compose version 1.22. If you use older versions it doesn't work. Please update your docker compose

Comment: Thank you @mulg0r. That helped.

Comment: You don't need `external: false` if you are reconnecting to an existing volume.